# How can I load a chart table with a default value in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm working on a Google Data Studio page which pulls data from a Google Sheet.
The use case of this page is to display the data from a row (from the Google Sheet) based on a selection made from a filter (single select dropdown).

When the Google Data Studio page loads, by default, it loads all the data from the source and displays it on the chart tables, however I would like to display a blank page and the data should load only after a selection is made from the filter dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve this problem. In the drop-down filter settings, in the "default selection" field, you can enter text by default that does not match any of the possibilities of the list items will be displayed in the drop-down list. It might be something like "-".

Thus, defining a default selection that does not exist in the list, it will start by default selected and will not correspond with any existing field, causing no information to be displayed in the table.

Comment: Hey, thanks Jhw_Trw for your response. I tried this, but only to realize my problem statement above is not complete. Apologies for that.

While the above suggestion does solve half of my problem, I'm left with another problem.
There are 3 dropdown single select filters which have cross filtering enabled. When I follow the above approach, the other filter dropdowns too get filtered to display no data, however I would like to exclude the other 2 dropdown filters from this approach and show all possible value.

Comment: In other words, lets say I have 3 filters. If I select an items from 1st filter it filters the data from the other 2, and vice versa. I believe this is called cross filtering?

My chart tables / fields on the form should load only when an item from 3rd filter dropdown is selected, and until then they should load blank.